# Adobe AIR won't include remote files !

Tags: air

Im building an AIR application using the HTML/JS SDK.

I can include scripts and stylesheets as long as they are in the same folder as my website, but no remote content fetched from the Internet can be included ! No remote scripts, neither from jquery nor from google... I put `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">` and nothing happens ! It is the case for every file, not only this one.

Have you ever run into this issue ? In the AIR documentation they seem to present us with big mashups and remote inclusions all the time, still it won't work for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this in AIR, but you need to work around the security restrictions as by default you can't do this from the first frame that is loaded. Thankfully it's not too hard.

You need to create an iframe in your main html page (e.g. index.html) and load all of your content into this. Your main html page then acts as a controller of sorts allowing you to call methods which require enhanced security permissions (file system etc..), while any code loaded into the iframe is allowed to load external media and scripts and also allowed to use JavaScript eval and other methods which are otherwise blocked in the main frame of the application.

You can read about it here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f08.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f07

Read the full page so you understand the concept, but pay particular attention to the sandboxRoot and documentRoot attributes when you are setting up the iframe.

Comment: ok but then Air becomes a chromeless browser, no more, right ?

Comment: Only in the lower frame. The main page (index.html) still has all of the enhanced security permissions so it can do things that a typical web browser environment can't, like work with the file system, desktop, and data. Using the parentSandboxBridge (see the link in my answer) you can expose these sorts of methods to pages in the child frame. It's the best of both worlds  :)

Comment: I'll just also add that the NativeProcess class allows you to invoke an external application which can then do pretty much anything else you want to do, and you can easily communicate with the original AIR app.